# Android SimpleXML library for XML parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I am parsing one long xml using SimpleXML library. Here is the Link of Long XML

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml

Now I want guidance regarding 
im:image tag

I have made the following POJO class

```
public class Image {
private int height;

public Image(@Attribute(name = "height") int height)
{
    this.height=height;
}
@Attribute(name = "height") 
public int getObjectHeight() {
    return height;
}
}
```

but this doesn't look me correct, because it will only deal with height...how to parse the content between these tags

```
<im:image height="170"> </im:image>
```

and my second question is what should be variable name in java ... because im:image is not allowed in java.

Please help me ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: What are all the details you need from the xml link...

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add the namespace for the  element

```
@Namespace(reference = "http://itunes.apple.com/rss", prefix = "im")
public class Image {
   @Element(name = "image ")
   private String image_url;

   @Attribute
   private int height;
}
```

Comment: And the OP needs to get the value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

The next code works fine

```
@Root(name = "feed")
static class Feed {
    @Element
    Image image;

}

@Root(name = "image")
static class Image {

    @Attribute(name = "height")
    int height;

    @Text
    String content;

}

@Test
public void testPrefixedTag() throws Exception {
    String xml = 
            "<feed xmlns:im=\"http://itunes.apple.com/rss\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">" +
            "<im:image height=\"170\">Content</im:image>" +
            "</feed>";
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    Feed feed = serializer.read(Feed.class, xml);
}
```

So, if you have reference to `im` namespace in your root tag (xml by your link has one) you can just use name of the child tags without it (as `image` in our case).

For parsing content between tags you use `@Text` annotation.